# Laravel Edit View not prefilling values

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-9

I am working on a Laravel 9 project that I inherited, and this is my first exposure to Laravel, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have been trying to get my edit views with components to prefill with the existing data, but nothing that I do will prefill these fields with current values from the model/database. Here is my `edit.blade.php`. I cannot seem to set the `value` property on this `x-input` component.

```
...
<form action="{{ route('users.update', $users) }}" method="post">
@method('put')
@csrf
<x-input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    fieldtitle="name"
    placeholder="Name"
    class="w-full"
    autocomplete="off" 
    :value="@old('name', $users->name)">
</x-input>
    
<x-input
    type="text"
    name="email"
    fieldtitle="email"
    placeholder="Email"
    class="w-full"
    autocomplete="off"
    :value="@old('email', $users->email)">
</x-input>

<x-button class="mt-6">Save User</x-button>
```

The `x-input` input component is in `resources/views/components`. While bubbling around, I did discover that if I remove `'value' => ''` from `@props`, the values will prefill, but it would be a mistake to leave it this way without understanding why! Here is `input.blade.php`

```
@props(['disabled' => false, 'fieldtitle' => '', 'value' => ''])

<input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50']) !!}>

@error($fieldtitle)
    <div class="text-red-600 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Here is my view in the browser
[image]
I do not think I should make this change permanent without understanding what and why!

**Question(s)**
So my question is multifaceted. Why can `value` be assigned when it is not in `@props`? What is `@props` for? What is the proper way to handle this situation? Are you aware of any good training on this subject?

Comment: Heya, can I see how you render your component?

Comment: @geertjanknapen added it to my question, i was unsure how to add it as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent worked with blade components, but it seems odd that you don use the value passed to the component here.

```
<input 
    {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} 
    {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50']) !!}
    value="{{ $value }}" {{--Here--}}
>
```

I think that when you remove the 'value' => '' from the @props, you are letting the component use the value tag to assign the value directly to the rendered input, and when you add it, only pass the value to the component and its never used. Give it a try and tell us if something happens.

Comment: Adding `value="{{ $value }}" ` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Props of the component will not be available in the `$attributes`

So, if you want to extract it as a prop, you will need to use the following syntax

```
<input value={{ $value }} ... />
```

Or simply remove it from the props to be rendered with `{{ $attributes->merge(...) }}`  syntax

BTW: for disabled you could use `@disabled` directive provided by blade (since laravel 9)

```
<input @disabled($disabled) ... />
```